# Преобразование из строки в число на си

Tags: c

Есть у меня строка введенная с клавиатуры. Нужно из этой строки получить число. Число берется вначале строки если строка будит вида 123 вася пупкин то итоговое число 132
Форматы ввода следующие:

```
0xac
0b1101
123
564.75
```

Написал следующий код:

```
char text[256];

memset(text,0,sizeof(text));

popStrCalc(&StrCalc, text); // выгрузка из стека

char * p2=text;

if(*p2 == '0'){
        switch (*(p2+1)) {
            case 'x':
            case 'X':{
                resI = strtol(p2+2,NULL,16);
                    pushMcalcI(&MCALC,resI); // загрузка в стек
                break;
            };
            case 'b':
            case 'B': {
                resI = strtol(p2+2,NULL,2);
                    pushMcalcI(&MCALC,resI);
                break;
            };
        }
}
else{
    resI = strtol(text,NULL,10);
        pushMcalcI(&MCALC,resI);
}
```

Проблема не могу понять как можно отличить числа float от int. Преобразовать float хочу '(float)strtod(text,NULL);'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отличить можно по простому признаку - в float есть либо точка либо буква `e`

```
if (strchr(text, '.') == NULL && (strchr(text, 'e') == NULL || strchr(text, 'E') == NULL)) {
    puts("it looks like float");
}
```

но можно заменить на одну функцию

```
if (strpbrk(text, ".eE") != NULL) {
    puts("it looks like float");
}
```

и есть ещё один случай - если число слишком длинное. Оно хоть и выглядит как целое, но в 32/64 может не влезть. Тут уже по обстоятельствам.